# Apply if-else function to each cell in a dataframe results in ambiguous exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a `pandas` `dataframe` like this:

| index | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 15 | 16 |

The number of columns and column names can be variable but it always includes a numeric value. I want to replace the values with either `-1`, `0` or `1` dependet on the value and some thresholds (`low` and `high`).

I thought about defining a `lambda` function and just using `apply`.

```
df.apply(lambda x: -1 if x < low else (1 if x > high else 0))
```

But that doesn't work due to following exception:

```
'The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'
```

I'm not really sure why this happens and what would be the best (also regarding performance) solution. Any advice/help is welcome.

Comment: Why not use `np.select` with the full df. loops can be slow here: `np.select([df<low,df>high],[-1,1],0)` this will return an array of same shape as df which you can assign back or create a new df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`pandas.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), which applies a function element-wise:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: -1 if x < low else (1 if x > high else 0))
```

The method [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) applies a function along a given axis (default is column-wise).

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the lambda the full dataframe, but you need to send it a column:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].apply(lambda x: -1 if x < low else (1 if x > high else 0))
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. But what should I do if I actually don't know the column name (they can be variable) and I want to apply this function to every column at once?

Comment: See above. iterate through columns